# Mail sniffer with Symfony2

Tags: email, symfony, sniffer, ticket-system

is there any way to make some Mail Sniffer with Symfony 2?

I will explain mi propurse...

I'm developing some ticketing system, and we would like to have this tool connected in any way to our mail server, then it will scan the pool for "Ticket no: 1234" tag inside subject of every email, if "Ticket no: 1234" is found, we want to append the content of the email to our History log inside BD with 1234 as TicketId, this is a good way to improve our ticket resolving time...

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your Mail-Server with PHP, sure. Please try to improve your question on the details.

Here are the native IMAP functions:

http://php.net/manual/de/ref.imap.php

And a nicer wrapper library for that:

https://github.com/tedivm/Fetch